How to update my application's Trust Store for Apple's new root CA?
Apple says: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09za8wzy

Apple Push Notification service server certificate update October 17,
2024
The Certification Authority (CA) for Apple Push Notification service
(APNs) is changing. APNs will update the server certificates in
sandbox on January 20, 2025, and in production on February 24, 2025.
All developers using APNs will need to update their application’s
Trust Store to include the new server certificate: SHA-2 Root :
USERTrust RSA Certification Authority certificate.
To ensure a smooth transition and avoid push notification delivery
failures, please make sure that both old and new server certificates
are included in the Trust Store before the cut-off date for each of
your application servers that connect to sandbox and production.
At this time, you don’t need to update the APNs SSL provider
certificates issued to you by Apple.

What does this mean for developers? What steps do I take in XCode to update the application's Trust Store, and do I need to re-submit the application to the App Store? Do I need to add the CA to Keychain Access?
I couldn't find much information about a "Trust Store" in XCode. Is this Trust Store on the server side instead? I have seen that "FCM already takes care of it" on their end, for example.
Furthermore, what's with the APNs SSL provider certificates?
Google's Gemini says:

Managed by the OS: You typically don't need to manually manage the
trust store directly in your app code, as Apple's operating system
automatically includes a set of trusted root certificates.

